# Downloading Files from Firebase Storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a function that when clicked downloads a file from firebase storage. I have implemented the function as in the firebase documentation v8. I have also applied the cors policy to allow downloads but the problem is that file is still not being downloaded and I am not getting an error.
Kindly help on this.
Below is my download function.

```js
const handleDownloadFile = async file => {
    try {
      const url = file.downloadURL;
      console.log(file);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = event => {
        const blob = xhr.response;
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

The function accepts the details of the file. Below is a sample object that

```js
{
  name: 'Ndov network LOGO - 400.png',
  downloadURL: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tki…=media&token=2680cc-4043-4676-992a-7e64fe8342f2',
  uuid: '1b1c0a4b-80a5-42d4-a698-719a26e3f281'
}
```

kindly help me understand why I am not getting any errors and the still download, not working.

Comment: what you mean by "the file is not being downloaded"? you're catching the response with this code: `const blob = xhr.response`, but you're not using that `blob` constant.

Answer (score 1):

This will open a window and ask the user where they want to save the file locally.

```js
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getBlob } from 'firebase/storage'

export const downloadFile = (refToFile) => {
  const storage = getStorage()
  const fileRef = ref(storage, refToFile)
  const blob = await getBlob(fileRef)
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = blobUrl
  link.download = 'myfilename.pdf'
  link.click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to download file on url that comes from API is to

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

or you can use some library for downloading files in blob format like
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Comment: Thanks for this. but window.open(url, '_blank'); opens the file on a new tab of the browser and the same for saveAs(url, file.name);.
But I wanted the file to be downloaded by the browser orwhatever download software the user has